# Where can I see remaining virtual user minutes (VUM) in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

In Azure DevOps how can I check the balance virtual user minutes (VUM)?

Answer (score 0):

I got the following solution:
1. Login to Azure DevOps
2. Go to Organization Settings 
3. Click on Billing
[Azure-DevOps-Billing-VUM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bed1J.png)

Comment: Much appreciate this solution shared here! You can accept your answer, so that others could directly know this is work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Organization Settings.
2. Under General, go to Billing.
3. Check the overview

[image: Billing overview]